# SSH Failing with User not known for local user

Tags: ssh, ldap, pam

I added a local user to my server (CentOS 6.5) but when I attempt to login as that user I'm getting denied by SSSD with the following error:

I can connect with my LDAP credentials fine but can't connect as any local user.

```
sshd[5174]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user tester2: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
```

nsswitch.conf:

```
.....
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
.......
```

sssd.conf:

```
[domain/default]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
sudo_provider = ldap
min_id = 8192
.....
[sssd]
domains = default
services = nss,pam,sudo
config_file_version = 2
[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root

[pam]

[sudo]

[domain/LOCAL]
id_provider = local
auth_provider = local
access_provider = permit
```

Confirming account:

```
# getent passwd tester2
tester2:x:9870:9872::/home/tester2:/bin/bash
```

It seems that PAM is getting stopped by SSSD during authentication. **How can I allow SSH login of local users and also LDAP users via SSSD?**

Comment: Would filter_users work under nss or pam?

Comment: I ended up having to remove pam_access from password-auth and system-auth.